# Simplest OptaPlanner example - is only construction heuristic enough?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm new into OptaPlanner and I'm trying to create an as simple as possible app that assigns few employees to some shifts. The only rule is that one employee can be assigned to one shift per day. I wonder if following solver configuration is not enough:

```
<solver>
   <solutionClass>com.test.shiftplanner.ShiftPlanningSolution</solutionClass>
   <entityClass>com.test.shiftplanner.ShiftAssignment</entityClass>

   <scoreDirectorFactory>
       <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
       <scoreDrl>rules.drl</scoreDrl>
   </scoreDirectorFactory>

   <!-- Solver termination -->
   <termination>
       <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
   </termination>

   <constructionHeuristic>
       <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
   </constructionHeuristic>
</solver>
```

because the collection of ShiftAssignment at ShiftPlanningSolution class remains EMPTY even though the Solver.solve() finishes and getBestSolution() returns something. What's more it seems that my rules at rules.drl are not fired at all. I even added a dummy rule just to see if it is triggered:

```
rule "test"
    when
        shiftAssignment : ShiftAssignment()
    then
        System.out.println(shiftAssignment);
end
```

and it's not fired at all.

So what are my mistakes here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As  of 6.3.0.Beta2, having `<constructionHeuristic>` or `<localSearch>` element is optional: it just uses a good default algo out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rule should be doing something with `scoreHolder`, see docs chapter 5. But despite that, you should see that rule being fired once for every ShiftAssignement instance in your dataset - check if you have any in there.

Comment: Thanks, you've pointed out my mistake! I misunderstood whole procedure. I thought that if I have a list of Shift and a list of Employee I don't have to initialize list of ShiftAssignment (I thought that planner will do that). Now when I have a collection of ShiftAssignment objects with Shift property set, planner works fine!